# How to parse YAML to a map with snakeyaml

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

My YAML files look something like this.

```
values:
  key1:
    subkey1:
      type: abc
      value: someValue
    subkey3:
      type: xyz
      value: someOtherValue

  key2:
    subkey2:
      type: def
      value: yetAnotherValue
```

I can parse them into a map structure (`Map<String,Key>`) with snakeyaml. The keys of the map would be `key1` and `key2` in the example above.

Here is my code to achieve this:

```
public Map<String, Keys> parse(InputStream inputStream) {
  Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new Constructor(Values.class));
  ((Values) yaml.load(inputStream)).getValues();

private static class Values {
  public Map<String, Keys> keys;

  public Map<String, Keys> getKeys() {
    return keys;
  }
}
```

In my `Keys` class I have:

```
public class Keys {

  private SomeClass subkey1;
  private SomeClass subkey2;
  private SomeClass subkey3;

  // getters and setter
  ...
}
```

This, of course, is ugly and not very generic. What I rather want is to have a map:

```
public class Keys {

  private Map<String, SomeClass> subKeys;
```

So instead of calling:

```
map.get("key1").getSubkey2().getValue();
```

I would then call

```
map.get("key1").get("subkey2").getValue();
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing but I can't figure out how to tell snakeyaml to map into such a structure.

**EDIT**:
I removed the top-level `values` and changed my code to map into the default structure of `Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>`. This works fine but it's a bit cumbersome to work with these objects.

So maybe my question can be rephrased: how would my Java classes and snakeyaml configuration need to look like to map into a structure like this:

Top level:
`Map<String, Keys>`

The class `Keys` then contains another map:
`Map<String, Element>`

And finally `Element` has two fields: `type` and `value`.